# SpringBoot reactive, issue timing @Timed with micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

*What I am trying to achieve:*

Gather some metrics, such as **time** using micrometer on a SpringBoot application within a **reactive** pipeline.

*what I tried:*

```
    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(final MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }
```

```
@Service
public class MyClass {

    public Flux<String> mainReactivePipelineETL() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) //Actual would be an aggressive flux from Kafka or http
                .map(i -> transformToComplexStringMethodIssueWithTimed(i));
    }

    @Timed("search_for_me")
    private String transformToComplexStringMethodIssueWithTimed(Long i) {
        //do some complex transformations from an input to an output
        // I would like to time this operation, just this method
        // The time varies for each transformation, again, this is invoked within a reactive pipeline
        return ...;
    }

}
```

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

*Issue:*

As you can see, following the reference guide https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers, I have in my code the proper @Configuration (see class above) for the TimedAspect

Besides that, I do have the annotation on my method `@Timed("search_for_me")`

With all, I am still not able to see these particular metrics (I do see a bunch of other metrics from micrometer, just not this one `@Timed("search_for_me")`)

For instance, for the first 3 elements of my flux, let's say in this example, the first "transformation: takes 10ms, the second takes 5ms, the third takes 20ms, I was hoping to see the metrics with:

- a count of three
- 10ms -> 5ms -> 20ms (so that I can plot that in a graph)

However, nothing

*Question:*

What is the proper way to get those metrics in this reactive app?

Comment: Did you enable loadtime or compile time weaving? WIthout it this won't work.

Comment: Hey, thank you for looking into this. "loadtime or compile time weaving" I do not think I did. How to please?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, you could do a workaround and extract such methods to a different helper class.

This way even if you just have AOP, the annotation should trigger the timedAspect.